# How do I group multiple elements with table-row display without messing up the table?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am displaying some non-tabular information using a tabular layout, attempting to create an accordion functionality without jquery. What I am attempting to do should look similar to the following:

```
// HTML
<div class="table">
  <div class="row header">
    <span class="cell">ABCDEFGHIJ</span>
    <span class="cell">1234567890</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell">ABCDEFGHIJ</span>
      <span class="cell">1234567890</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell">ABCDEFGHIJ</span>
      <span class="cell">1234567890</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

/* CSS */
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The above doesn't work as intended, however. I tried changing the content `<div>` to different combinations of class names but the nested rows do not span across the entire width of the outer table in both cases, only within the first column.

If I am using actual tables, the above can be resolved using multiple `<tbody>` to implement the accordion. However, best practices would recommend contexts such as mine to not use tables, for which I am unable to find any relevant solution online. What is an equivalent solution for my problem?

Comment: The display for `<tbody>` tag is `table-row-group`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: table-row-group` solves your problem.

```
.content {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

Example below. Cheers!

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.content {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row header">
    <span class="cell">ABCDEFGHIJ</span>
    <span class="cell">1234567890</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell">ABCDEFGHIJ</span>
      <span class="cell">1234567890</span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <span class="cell">ABCDEFGHIJ</span>
      <span class="cell">1234567890</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```